# Flutter run fails to build and VS Code abnormally closes

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu OS to the latest version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu 2022.04), and I upgraded to Flutter 3.0.0 as well.
I created a Flutter project but now the problem is when I run the project( either on the terminal with "flutter run" or running it on VS Code), it closes VS Code abnormally without giving me any errors.

I have not added anything to this project, its a default or a base project that gets created when you create a new Flutter project

Has anyone come across this Issue? Please help?

Comment: Is this Ubuntu native or WSL2 on Windows?

Comment: can you run it with flutter version 2 or 1?

Comment: @Dabbel Its Ubuntu native

Comment: @anggadaz actually this is a default or a base project that gets built when you create a new project. I have not added anything.

Comment: Did you install either VS Code or Flutter via Snap? I've seen some odd issues where one of them was installed using Snap but the other was not (same goes for Chrome if running Flutter web apps). If one but not both came via Snap, I would try installing them both through Snap or neither to see if that helps.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny I decided to revert to Ubuntu 20.04 and everything worked. I think the new version of Ubuntu is the one that was giving me issues